# How to reorder the Group / Tier Pricing display in product edit

Tags: adminhtml, tiered-pricing, price-sorting

My client has 10 groups that receive discounts on their products, every product has a group price attached to it as per the attached image.

He has now requested that we reorder the prices in admin so they show with the highest price at the top, or alphabetically by group name rather than the current order (which is currently sorted by group id from what I can tell)

Can anyone point me in the correct direction to change this ordering?

[image: image of one of the group price setups]

Comment: Hi Curt,

Did you find the answer? Please let me know how you fix this.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the project took a turn to something completely different and this is still on the "To do" list.  As soon as I get an answer I'll update though!